# hyperlink to another sheet in table if checkbox is checked, but not if unchecked macro

Tags: excel, vba

I failed some code for an excel macro, which sends users to another sheet in an excel table once a checkbox is checked, but does nothing if it is unchecked.It is a form control checkbox and it is on the worksheet itself, not externally.

I tried this already, but no luck:

```
Sub CheckBox28_Click()
    If OptionButton1 = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet3!A1").Select
    ElseIf OptionButton1 = False Then
    End If


End Sub
```

It compiles, but nothing happens when assigned to checkbox

Please, help :)

Comment: Hi, if someone needs code then in most cases he needs to write that code himself (because this is not a free coding service). Try it own your own, show your efforts, show the code you already have (tried) and ask a question to it, explaining which errors you get and where or where you get stuck. • Actually it would be easier to do that with a button than a hyperlink.

Comment: Try using something like this: `If OptionButton1.Value = true then
        (action...)
    End if`, the idea is the if condition, when it's true (checked) you can go to the next tast and open the other Excel table.

Comment: Note that code in comments is not readable at all. Please always [edit] your original question to add code or more information.

Comment: Where is that CheckBox? On the worksheet or on a UserForm? If it is on the worksheet, then is it a FormControl or an ActiveX Control (both types exist and can be inserted on a sheet). We need to know which type you are using.

Comment: Hi, it is a form control and it is on the worksheet itself

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Form Control and not an ActiveX use the following

```
Sub CheckBox28_Click()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Select
    Else 
        'do something else
    End If
End Sub
```

Further details find here:

- [The Complete Guide to Excel Form Control Option Button VBA](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-option-button/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted the click box to do nothing if unchecked. So by checking it, you go to sheet 3!A1 and by unchecking it nothing happens. Running the above code gets a runtime error "The item with the specified name was not found. Which is funny, since the checkbox is there...

Comment: Actually you cannot "uncheck" an OptionButton. You probably mean a CheckBox then. The code works in my example I tested it. Have a look into the guide for more background information.